# How to include commit messages as changelog in HockeyApp?

Tags: teamcity, hockeyapp, changelog

It would be useful for us to include what commits are included in the latest version compared to the previously uploaded one.

We use TeamCity to build and a step is to upload to HockeyApp, however I'm not sure how we can add the mentioned part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [TeamCity REST API](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/REST+API#RESTAPI-Changes) to get the same information you'll find on the Changes UI tab in TeamCity. Parse these changes out however you like, and then you can include them in your HockeyApp release notes when you do the upload.